# Two applications using celery scheduled tasks: "Received unregistered task" errors in one of the workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

The scenario:

- Two unrelated web apps with celery background tasks running on same server.
- One RabbitMQ instance
- Each web app has its own virtualenv (including celery). Same celery version in both virtualenvs.

I use the following command lines to start a worker and a beat process for each application.

```
celery -A firstapp.tasks worker
celery -A firstapp.tasks beat
celery -A secondapp.tasks worker --hostname foobar
celery -A secondapp.tasks beat
```

Now everything seems to work OK, but in the worker process of `secondapp` I get the following error:

```
Received unregistered task of type 'firstapp.tasks.do_something'
```

Is there a way to isolate the two celery's from each other?

I'm using Celery version 3.1.16, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed the problem by creating a RabbitMQ vhost and configuring the second app to use that one.

Create vhost (and set permissions):

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost /secondapp
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /secondapp guest ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

And then change the command lines for the second app:

```
celery -A secondapp.tasks -b amqp://localhost//secondapp worker
celery -A secondapp.tasks -b amqp://localhost//secondapp beat
```